# How do I properly keep user logged in, in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am storing the token in a http only cookie and in redux and I am protecting my routes via getServerSideProps by checking req.cookies.token and if there is no token I redirect to login, the problem is if the user refreshes the page he can visit the protected routes because the token is still there, but to get the token on the client side I have to send a request to api/checkAuth which will return the data (token) in the cookie, this request I am sending from _app.js so I don't have to do in each page individually ( otherwise I could just sent the token from getServerSideProps to the page as props) but the problem is this request sent from _app.js takes time to finish while the user is allowed to visit the page and when I have request inside useEffect my token is not available immediately so I have to use token as dependency in the useEffect array and only send request if token exists, but this solution doesn't seem good to me, what is the correct way to do it?

Here is the way I am guarding routes:

```
const withAuth = (GetServerSidePropsFunction) => async (ctx) => {

  const token = ctx.req.cookies?.token || null;

  if (!token) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/login",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }


  return await GetServerSidePropsFunction(ctx);
};

export default withAuth;
```

And this is the request in _app.tsx that is being sent to get the token:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let token = (store as any).user?.token;
    if (!token) {
      fetch("/api/checkAuth", {
        method: "POST",
        body: "",
      })
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((cookieData) => {
          if (cookieData.token)
           store.dispatch(setUser(token: cookieData.token }));
             
        });
    }
  }, []);
```